# Create a model that only exists in the view and doesn't get saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

Whenever I create a new object, I want to create a nested object that is available in the view, but is not saved on submit.

So far, my controller for my main model looks like this:

```
def new
    @main = Main.new
    @tmp = Sub.new
    @tmp.hide = 1
    @main.subs << @tmp
end
```

Where `hide` is an integer field that designates whether it's the fake model or not.

My problem the `hide` value, doesn't appear to exist after I click submit (it exists in the views).

For example, if I submit normally, the `@tmp` is saved, along with any other fields. But if I try and display `hide` in show, `@tmp` is displayed, but it's `hide` value isn't.

`hide` defaults to nil. So it would appear after submit, the change in the controller is not present.

My understanding is I can use:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :subs, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |a| a[:hide] == 1 }`

In the `main` model, but this doesn't seem to work.

How can I create the model, either so it's never in the database, or deleted when the parent is saved to the database?

**In depth:**

I have an [`Experiments`](https://gist.github.com/631dce37e389793f844f) model that `has_many` [`exptypes`](https://gist.github.com/a10b9ad95baee06f8267).

In my [`form`](https://gist.github.com/af39bd3547fca01280f9) I used the nested-form gem, and as such (by virtue of trying to mix it with tabs), `@experiment.exptypes` **cannot** be empty.

The `hide` attribute is used on line 93 and 118 to determine whether to hide the tab or not.

This way, whenever an `experiment` is created, they'll be a fake `exptype` already in the array, and I don't want this saved on submission.

Comment: *doesn't save when going to the view/submit* Can you clarify what is happening; does the `hide` value appear correctly in the form / page after page-load (meaning you can inspect it and see it in the browser), or are you saying its not being sent properly when the form is submitted?

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself. I've rewritten the question. I'm saying the second, it does not appear to be sent after the page is submitted.

Comment: Ok that's more clear. See my answer below, let me know if it makes a difference. There could a couple of things causing this problem beyond how the `Sub` object is created in the controller, so if the solution fails, you may need to further isolate where the issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This may be an XY problem, so this proposed solution may not have an affect on the overall issue. If that is the case, we may need to see the `Sub` model and the form you referred to.*

In this kind of scenario, you will likely want to use the `build` ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)) association method to create a dependent `Sub` object. So your controller code would change like so:

```
def new
  @main = Main.new
  @main.subs.build(hide: 1)
end
```

This will create a new `Sub` object, but it will not be saved to the database. The `<<` method **does** save to the database, but this is typically not desired behaviour from the `new` resource route.

In your view form, you can still access the `Sub` objects as you would any dependent object, using `fields_for`. Example:

```
<% f.fields_for :subs do |subs_form| %>
    <%= subs_form.text_field :hide %>
<% end %>
```

which will give you a text field already populated with the `hide` value you set in the controller.

Let me know whether that makes sense.

Comment: This approach works for the view (I am able to access the `:hide` attribute. However, it does not stop the model from being saved to the database when I submit.

Comment: @Darkstarone The `reject_if` doesn't remove it? Does it make a difference if you change the condition to `a[:hide] == "1"`?

Comment: Added links to my actual code, as well as a basic explanation.

Comment: @Darkstarone I don't know if this is overly simplistic, or if I'm still not quite getting it, but if you're hiding the tab for the `exptype` that has `hide == 1`, should you move the `f.fields_for :exptypes...` block inside the if statement? That way its not rendered if its "hidden" and no need to worry about whether its being created, or having to reject it post-submit.

Comment: Annoyingly, the `nested-form` gem requires that the fields be produced. Otherwise it acts as if the `@experiment.exptypes` is empty, and throws an error. That's why I've created the fields, and hidden them.

Comment: @Darkstarone Ah ok, I see. So 2 things, after implementing this change, is it still not sending the `hide` value to the server (aka it is **not** in the parameter map)? Have you added the `hide` field to the strong parameters filter?

Comment: It's still not in the params, and it is in the strong parameters filter. I have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2fbc862ec550bc8d359f) of a sample params and my strong method

Comment: Theres certainly some raised eyebrows here. Do you want to show your exptype_fields partial, just to ensure there's nothing odd going on

Comment: Just realised I hadn't included a `hidden_field` for `hide` in the partial, and that's why it wasn't being captured. Thank you for being patient with me and  guiding me towards the solution for my rather rookie mistake!

Comment: I was just about to say, I don't see it in there. :) No problem, glad you were able to figure it out in the end.